# Entity Framework database first change column mapping

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and I want to do some mapping between an existing database and the entities created from Entity Framework (from Visual Studio 2013 pro). I have a table named "customer" and the following columns :

- customer_id
- customer_name
- address

I want this to be translated as an entity like this :

```
public partial class Customer {
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the uppercase of the class name, and the PascalCase and no underscore for all of the properties.

Is there a way to do this with

- A Visual Studio GUI of some sort
- Annotations in the entity (like map db column "customer_id" to property "CustomerId)
- A config file (ex. xml)
- Another way

Note that I'm aware that with code first's approach it is possible, but I'm using database first. I tried to edit the .edmx via Visual Studio's GUI but it cause reference losses (cannot find file CustomerId.cs) and I don't know where to edit this reference.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Open a new project your solution. May be you can try opening a Class Library project. Right click on new classlibrary project and select Add -> New Item.

Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model and follow step in the Entity Generation Wizard.

It will generate your entities from the Database.